# Keep only matched patterns of Regex.Split in C#

Tags: c#, regex, split

I want to keep only the matched patterns of `Regex.Split()` and discard other text.

**Example**

Assumingly I want to print only the upper case words from a text.

```
Console.WriteLine("Give input");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

string pattern = @"([A-Z]{2,})";
string[] words = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

foreach (var w in words)
  Console.WriteLine(w)
```

Typing *MY_NAME_IS_george_WHATS_YOUR_NAME* provides the output bellow.

```
Type an identifier
MY_NAME_IS_george_WHATS_YOUR_NAME

MY
_
NAME
_
IS
_george_
WHATS
_
YOUR
_
NAME

Type an identifier
```

As you can see the splitted array includes strings that don't match the pattern. How can I avoid printing the text that didn't matched by the regex?

Comment: Use Regex.Match and retrieve the Groups from the match instead.

Comment: Maybe you meant `Regex.Matches`

Comment: Could you kindly accept the answer of Stefano if it has solved the issue, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you missunderstand what split does.

> Splits an input string into an array of substrings at the positions
>   defined by a regular expression pattern.

if you want to split and than print the only upper case you have to do a match also

```
Console.WriteLine("Give input");
string input = Console.ReadLine();

string pattern = @"([A-Z]{2,})";
string[] words = Regex.Split(input, pattern);

foreach (var w in words)
 if(Regex.IsMatch(w,pattern)
  Console.WriteLine(w);
```

Or just use `Regex.Matches(input,pattern);`

Comment: `foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches("MY_NAME_IS_george_WHATS_YOUR_NAME", @"([A-Z]{2,})"))
    Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[0].Captures[0].Value);`

Comment: Guys Regex.Matches(input,pattern) returns a collection with all matched strings.

Comment: Btw I upvoted only by the fact that I indeed seemed to missunderstood what split does :D

Comment: @Longoon12000 feel free to add it under my simple "just use `Regex.Matches(input,pattern);` "